# How to communicate between threads in Scala?

Tags: scala

I have a class with some methods in Scala, each method has an execution time, for example `methodA` takes 10 seconds and `methodB` takes 5 seconds. and each method calls asynchronously.when I call  `methodB`, it should cancel the thread that is running another methods. I first call methodA, and 2 seconds later I call methodB. What is the best solution for this problem?

```
def methodA()={
    async{
        // a job that takes 10 seconds
    }
}
def methodB()={
   async{
       // other methods should stop their job
      // a job that takes 5 second
   }
}

def async[T](fn: => Unit): Unit = scala.actors.Actor.actor {
    fn
}

.....

methodA()
methodB()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an idea, based on the assumption that your method is actively checking whether it should still run or cancel:

```
import concurrent.{ExecutionContext, Future, Promise, blocking, future, promise}

case class Cancelled() extends RuntimeException

object Job {
  def apply[A](fun: (() => Boolean) => A)(implicit ctx: ExecutionContext): Job[A] = 
    new Job[A] {
      private val p = promise[A]
      def result = p.future
      def cancel(): Unit = p.tryFailure(Cancelled())

      p tryCompleteWith future {
        fun(() => !p.isCompleted)
      }
    }
}
trait Job[A] {
  def result: Future[A]
  def cancel(): Unit
}
```

So `Job` embodies a future along with a `cancel()` method. Your example could be similar to this:

```
import ExecutionContext.Implicits.global

val a = Job { active =>
  for (i <- 1 to 100 if active()) {
    blocking {
      Thread.sleep(1000)  // doing actual heavy work here
      println(s"A $i")
    }
  }
}

val b = Job { active =>
  for (i <- 1 to 20 if active()) {
    blocking {
      Thread.sleep(1000)  // doing actual heavy work here
      println(s"B $i")
    }
  }
  println("Goodbye A...")
  a.cancel()
}
```

I have also seen a rather [harsh variant](https://gist.github.com/andrewconner/6362491#file-futuregoodies-scala-L113) that calls `Thread.interrupt`.

Comment: Good solution, but in my project, threads or jobs can not find each other to cancel. in your solution `b` knows that there is an `a` job

Comment: Ah well, then you just need to a keep a global list of running jobs. It should be straight forward to register them within the `Job.apply` method.

Comment: Ok, but what is the identifier of job inside the apply method to register it in a global map?